# How do I get suspend working on an Acer Extensa 4420 laptop?

Tags: 12.04, suspend

When I click Suspend, all it does is the internet gets disconnected for a few seconds and than I get connected again.
I have a Acer Extensa 4420 laptop.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo pm-suspend`. Tell us whether this generates any error messages. Then, type `dmesg` and post the last two pages (use http://paste.ubuntu.com for that).

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the very same problem with an Acer Extensa with Intel + Intel internal video card. I have updated the graphics drivers from oibaf ppa repo:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/

after that suspend worked flawlessly. Try it and report here if it worked for you.

Hope this helps.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)